# Add Observer and Selector in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift2, swift3

I am really struggling to understand the new syntax for observers.

Can you help me translate this to Swift 3.

```
nc.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MapViewController.locationUpdated(_:)), name: LocationNotification.kLocationUpdated, object: nil)
nc.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MapViewController.locationAuthorizationStatusChanged(_:)), name: LocationNotification.kAuthorizationStatusChanged, object: nil)
nc.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MapViewController.locationManagerDidFailWithError(_:)), name: LocationNotification.kLocationManagerDidFailWithError, object: nil)
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to make the method accepting the notifications public (if its on a different controller).

And you should also add the processor tag `objc` so objective-c methods can call it.

Assign Observers:

```
nc.addObserver(
    self,
    selector: #selector(received(notification:)),
    name: LocationNotification.kLocationUpdated, object: nil
)
```

Handle notifications:

```
@objc public func locationUpdated(notification:Notification) {
    //Do something
}
```

Hope this helps! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of your code is valid for Swift 3. With this syntax, I am assuming your `LocationNotification` object looks something like this:

```
struct LocationNotification {
    static let kLocationUpdated = Notification.Name(rawValue: "LocationUpdated")
    static let kAuthorizationStatusChanged = Notification.Name(rawValue: "AuthorizationStatusChanged")
    static let kLocationManagerDidFailWithError = Notification.Name(rawValue: "LocationManagerDidFailWithError")
}
```